# Python subprocess running from mingw fails to find binaries

Tags: python, subprocess, mingw

I have a set of python modules that I want to work both on linux and on MinGW (Windows).

While subprocess works fine with on Linux, on windows subprocess.call/Popen keep throwing errors saying the required binary can not be found.

For example, I use Xilinx's Vivado a lot (EDA tool). While just typing "vivado" in mingw prompt works fine and vivado is launched, if I try to call vivado through subprocess, I get an error saying the file can not be found.

My mingw environment path variable contains: `/c/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.2/bin` which is where the vivado binary is found. If I launch python and do this,

```
print os.environ['PATH']
```

I see it contains: `C:\\Xilinx\\Vivado\\2015.2\\bin;`

So I guess python performed the appropriate translations upon launch.

Also, if instead of vivado I try to launch vivado.bat (file contained in the same directory as the binary) from python's subprocess, everything works and the binary is launched.

The vivado binary has execution permissions...

So my question is. Is this problem something known? what is the cleanest way to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the context of the question (python version, path, etc.) specially the part of the code that is starting the process.

Comment: first it's not python that changes the path, it's MinGW. Second, can you post your code and the exact output you're getting? (with the PATH printing too). and if you have 2 "vivado" files (one .bat and one .exe, you may want to specify extensions, because that can be a problem. What is the extension of the other "vivado" file? Help us help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies but I already solved the issue. I had done some dynamic modifications to subprocess.Popen to detect the current platform and call windows powershell or cmd depending on the windows version but I realise this approach was all wrong. I did that because I did not think the issue had to do with the tool I was invoking in particular, so I did not want to change the binary called in function of the platform, I now realise this is much cleaner and probably much better. I am now calling the .bat when in windows and the binary otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers the OP exactly, but I think it is highly related: consider this example, where the executable path is written Windows-style, with backslashes:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os
import subprocess

NOTEPADPATH = r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"

print("NOTEPADPATH is {}".format(NOTEPADPATH))

proc_notepad = subprocess.Popen([NOTEPADPATH], shell=False)
```

If I run this in MSYS2 shell, it fails:

```
$ python3 test.py
NOTEPADPATH is C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test4.py", line 11, in <module>
    proc_notepad = subprocess.Popen([NOTEPADPATH], shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe': 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe'
```

If I run this in Anaconda 3 shell Python3 (which is apparently compiled for Windows natively), it succeeds (Notepad is started):

```
(base) C:\msys64\tmp>python test.py
NOTEPADPATH is C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe
```

---

If we now change the executable path, so it uses forward slash as path separator, instead of backslash:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os
import subprocess

NOTEPADPATH = r"C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe"

print("NOTEPADPATH is {}".format(NOTEPADPATH))

proc_notepad = subprocess.Popen([NOTEPADPATH], shell=False)
```

... then it succeeds both in MSYS2, where Notepad is started:

```
$ python3 test.py
NOTEPADPATH is C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
```

... and in Anaconda 3 shell Python3:

```
(base) C:\msys64\tmp>python test.py
NOTEPADPATH is C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, Python doesn't seem to find executables with the `.cmd` extension. For both MinGW versions and the standard Windows packages, despite `.cmd` being listed in the `PATHEXT` environment variable. The solution for me was to to add the extension to the command:

```
# executable with .exe extension
>>> subprocess.run(("node", "--version"), check=True)
v18.15.0
CompletedProcess(args=('node', '--version'), returncode=0)

# executable with .cmd extension
>>> subprocess.run(("npm", "--version"), check=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Environment\Python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Environment\Python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Environment\Python\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1493, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>> subprocess.run(("npm.cmd", "--version"), check=True)
9.5.0
CompletedProcess(args=('npm.cmd', '--version'), returncode=0)
```

So if you are building a cross-platform app you will need to do an OS check and append the extension before execution.

```
command = "npm"
if sys.platform == "win32":
  command += ".cmd"
```